# How to find out file type , is Folder and Image type in android

Tags: android, file

Hi guys this is my code but when I try to get .png/.jpg image so it;s return me .png folder also  and my app crash is there any physical property to find out only folder type without check extension

```
                   File a1=new File(ass[i].getAbsolutePath();
                       File[] a2 = a1.listFiles();
                               if (a2.length>0) {
                               for (int in=0;in<a2.length;in++){
                                   String name=a2[in].getName();
                                   if (name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg"))
                                       list_count_images.add(a2[in].getName());// Image Type
                                   else  if (name.indexOf(".") == -1)
                                       list_count_fils.add(a2[in].getName());// Folder Type
                               }
```

thank you in advance...

Comment: Please try to explain your problem a little more.The statements are a little ambiguous

Comment: folder is directory not file

Comment: actually i want to find out images and folder from directory but in my directory many folders are save with .png extension and my app also read these folder like a image when user click on these so app will crash so is there any way to find out the folder and image withe his physical  any type...

Answer (score 1):

Use `File.isDirectory()` to verify if the `File` entry is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

This method will try to load the file as as bitmap to decode the width and height:

```
public static boolean isImage( File file ) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile( file.getPath() );
        return options.outWidth > 0 && options.outHeight > 0;
    } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you need a solution for folder?

Comment: The other answer on this thread is right for that. Just call `File.isDirectory` to check if it's a directory.